# Write XML Elements with attribute to list

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this XML File and want write all values with MGU tags that are under the < Norm > with attribute Name="TL 52146" to a list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Normen>
  <Norm Name="TL 52146">
    <MGU>PV 1401</MGU>
    <MGU>PV 1425</MGU>
    <MGU>PV 1448</MGU>
  </Norm>
</Normen>
```

The expected result would be:

- PV 1401
- PV 1425
- PV 1448

When I use this code I just get one list element with all MGUs in it but I want every MGU to be a seperate entry in my list:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data/data.xml");
var ChildsOfNorm = from element in doc.Descendants("Norm")
                   where element.Attribute("Name").Value == "TL 52146"
                   select element;
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change the code to the following:

```
var ChildsOfNorm = doc
     .Descendants("Norm")
     .Where(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "TL 52146")
     .Elements();
```

If you only want to get the `MGU` elements, change the `Elements()` call to `Elements("MGU")`.

This should get all wanted elements.

With the given xml

```
foreach (var v in ChildsOfNorm)
    Console.WriteLine(v.Value);
```

outputs:

> PV 1401
>   PV 1425
>   PV 1448